# Generate all id-time pairs when merging two dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to merge two dataframes together based on the columns `id` and `time`. I think an example is more efficient to show what I want to do:

- this is what I have:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
              time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
              val1 = c(2000:2005))

  id     time  val1
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 a         1  2000
2 a         2  2001
3 b         1  2002
4 b         2  2003
5 c         1  2004
6 c         2  2005

df2 <- tibble(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
              time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3),
              val2 = c(2000:2005))

  id     time  val2
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 a         1  2000
2 a         2  2001
3 b         1  2002
4 b         2  2003
5 c         2  2004
6 c         3  2005
```

- this is the desired output:

```
  id     time  val1  val2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1  2000  2000
2 a         2  2001  2001
3 a         3    NA    NA
4 b         1  2002  2002
5 b         2  2003  2003
6 b         3    NA    NA
7 c         1  2004    NA
8 c         2  2005  2004
9 c         3    NA  2005
```

Basically, I want to generate rows with `time` equal to 3 for each `id`, not just the one who has one period equal to 3. I would like the solution to be as short as possible (and preferably based on `dplyr` functions, but the compacity of the code comes first).

Surely this question has already been asked but I can't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a `full_join`, we can use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
full_join(df1, df2,, by = c('id', 'time')) %>% 
       complete(id, time)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  id     time  val1  val2
#  <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1 a         1  2000  2000
#2 a         2  2001  2001
#3 a         3    NA    NA
#4 b         1  2002  2002
#5 b         2  2003  2003
#6 b         3    NA    NA
#7 c         1  2004    NA
#8 c         2  2005  2004
#9 c         3    NA  2005
```

Comment: so simple, thanks (I mark it as answer as soon as I can)